# Why is this click event triggered for an unrelated element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

I'm working on this Tooltip where if you mouse over it it'll show a tooltip:

[image]

But if you tap on it (with your finger) it'll show full screen (for mobile support):

[image]

Code looks like this:

```
export default function Tooltip({ message, children }: Props) {
    const [showSmallTip, setShowSmallTip] = useState(false);
    const [showBigTap, setShowBigTip] = useState(false);
    const ref = useRef(null);
    const pos = useBoundingBox(ref);

    const handleMouseEnter = useCallback(() => {
        setShowSmallTip(true);
    }, [setShowSmallTip]);

    const handleMouseLeave = useCallback(() => {
        setShowSmallTip(false);
    }, [setShowSmallTip]);

    const handleTap = useCallback(() => {
        console.log("TAP!")
        setShowBigTip(true);
        setShowSmallTip(false);
    }, [setShowBigTip]);

    const closeFullscreen = useCallback((ev:MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
        console.log('CLOSE!!!')
        ev.stopPropagation();
        setShowBigTip(false);
        setShowSmallTip(false);
    }, [setShowBigTip]);

    const onTap = useTap(handleTap);

    return <>
        <Wrapper ref={ref} onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave} {...onTap}>
            {children}
        </Wrapper>
        {showSmallTip ? <End container={SCROLL_ROOT}><StyledTooltip style={{ top: pos.bottom, left: (pos.left + pos.right) / 2 }}>{message}</StyledTooltip></End> : null}
        {showBigTap ? <End><FullscreenTip onClick={closeFullscreen}><FullscreenText>{message}</FullscreenText></FullscreenTip></End>:null}
    </>
}
```

Where `useTap` is:

```
export default function useTap<T = Element>(callback: VoidCallback, options?: Options): TouchEvents<T> {
    const data = useRef<TouchData>(Object.create(null));

    return useMemo<TouchEvents<T>>(() => {
        const opt = { ...DEFAULT_OPTIONS, ...options } as Required<Options>;

        return {
            onTouchStart(ev) {
                data.current = {
                    time: ev.timeStamp,
                    x: ev.changedTouches[0].screenX,
                    y: ev.changedTouches[0].screenY,
                }
            },
            onTouchEnd(ev) {
                const mx = ev.changedTouches[0].screenX - data.current.x;
                const my = ev.changedTouches[0].screenY - data.current.y;
                const moved = Math.sqrt(mx**2 + my**2);
                const elapsed = ev.timeStamp - data.current.time;
                if (moved < opt.moveThreshold && elapsed < opt.pressDelay) {
                    // setTimeout(() => {
                        callback();
                    // }, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }, [callback, options])
}
```

The issue I'm having is when you tap on the icon it opens and closes the fullscreen tooltip immediately. i.e., it prints

```
TAP!
CLOSE!!!
```

with one single tap.

Now I know `touchend` fires before `click`, but what I can't figure out is why that would even matter?? If you look at my placement of the `{...onTap}` and `onClick={closeFullscreen}` handlers, they're siblings. The events shouldn't bubble that way (neither in the native DOM nor [React's VDOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html#event-bubbling-through-portals)), and I certainly didn't click on `<FullscreenTip>` so how on earth is `closeFullscreen` firing?

`<End>` is a portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**DEMO**](https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-sun-of03i)

Try to call `ev.preventDefault()` on `onTouchEnd`.

According to [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/#touch-interface) the `touchend` event is *"cancelable"* which means that you can use `.preventDefault()` to prevent mouse events.

> If the preventDefault method is called on this event, it should prevent any default actions caused by any touch events associated with the same active touch point, including mouse events or scrolling.

[image]

Comment: That does work, but I'm still not sure why `.shadow` is receiving a click event. I'm surprised that the overlay would even render between touchend and click, but I suppose it does if an event is firing on it. Even so, do you not need a mousedown/touchstart event on that same element to trigger a `click`?

Comment: `.shadow` is receiving a click event because it's enough time to render it and handle the click event after. `click` event is about a "point" _(a finger for mobile devices)_, while `mousedown` event is only for a mouse. I think such a decision was made for compatibility reasons.

Comment: That's why there is no need to handle `mousedown/touchstart`, `click` is enough.

Comment: I do need a touchstart event though if I want to discount long-presses, drags and mouse events, no?

Comment: Also, MDN says "An element receives a click event when a pointing device button (such as a mouse's primary mouse button) is **both pressed and released** while the pointer is located inside the element." but I haven't found any documentation about how click works on mobile yet. I would have thought that entailed a finger touch and release, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: I tried to find a single word about this behavior, but couldn't find anything useful, only some mentions about it.